# Adding a indication to script in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have a small script that saves data in Google Sheets. It looks at 3 cells and 'saves' them below. I have it set on a 'Project Trigger' every few hours and I also have a button. I would like to, in Column D, insert into the cell some text that indicates wether is was a trigger, or a manual button click (`"Trigger"`,`"Manual"`).

What I get at the moment is:

```
URL : follower_count : date
```

I would like:

```
URL : follower_count : date : trigger_status
```

Here is the code:

```
// function to save data
function saveData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var url = sheet.getRange('Sheet1!A3').getValue();
  var follower_count = sheet.getRange('Sheet1!B3').getValue();
  var date = sheet.getRange('Sheet1!C3').getValue();
  sheet.appendRow([url, follower_count, date]);
}
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Google Apps Script [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events):

> Simple triggers and installable triggers let Apps Script run a
>   function automatically if a certain event occurs. When a trigger
>   fires, Apps Script passes the function an event object as an argument,
>   typically called `e`.

Hence, when your function `saveData` is called by the trigger it will be invoked with an argument. This way you will be able to tell if its "Manual" or "Trigger". I.e:

```
function saveData(e) {
  var isTrigger = false; 
  if(e){
    isTrigger = true;
  }
  ...
}
```